# How to Expire Cached Passwords in Windows Peer-To-Peer Network

Tags: windows, network-share

I have a colleague that has a Windows Peer-To-Peer Network.  He has an application such that he has shared network folders where he wants an employee to be able access the shared folder by typing in a password, then some time later, if another employee at the same work center wants to access the same shared network folder, he wants the employee to have to retype the password to gain access to the share.

Currently, Windows is caching the password so the 2nd employee has automatic access to the share.

What do you recommend?

The way I see it, he could:

1. log out and log back in for the 2nd employee.  I think that will clear the password cache
2. Find a way to clear the cached password (I don't know how to do that), perhaps through Windows Scripting Host

I would imagine that since he doesn't have a Server, installing a Windows Server on the network is not really an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for "net use RESOURCE /delete /Y"

If you're mapping drive letters, substitute it in for RESOURCE .  If it is a network folder that isn't mapped, substitute the UNC of the folder for RESOURCE  ie "\computer\folder"

Run "net use" to show all your 'connected' resources.

Answer (score 0):

The "poor man's trust relationship" and peer-to-peer file sharing scenario:

- Create two user accounts on the "client" computer-- one for each employee. Set passwords on these accounts.
- Create the same two user accounts on the "server" computer-- again, one for each employee, with exactly the same spelling of usernames and exactly the same password.
- Open the local group policy on the "server" computer (Start / Run / GPEDIT.MSC) and modify the "Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts" to the "Classic" setting (located under the "Security Options" node of the "Local Policies" node of the "Security Settings" node of the "Windows Settings" node of the "Computer Configuration" node).

If the user changes their password on the "client" computer they'll need to have it changed on the "server" computer, too. (Here's where a Domain is your friend.)

You can use NTFS permissions on the "server" computer to protect files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a bat file that would connect, prompting for credentials, then run windows explorer. Once explorer is closed, the script would disconnect the drive and exit.

Ghetto I know.

Comment: Here is a better way from MS: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684